# How to get current project name in sbt build.scala

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multiple project sbt build using aggregator. How can I get the current project name in Build.scala?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
name.value
```

Since it contains a `.value`, it must be on the right-hand-side of a `:=`, `+=` or `++=`.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the case in which you want to get the proect name, if you have several of them and a setting like `name` then `.value`, like **sjrd** told, is your way. If you want to get current project name, for example to prompt in sbt shell, then you can extract it from the state, i.e - `(state: State) => Project.extract(state).currentProject.id`. Also if you have a `ProjectRef` availuable it has a value `project`.